# Create several "dev/xxx" in a single linux module?

Tags: driver, linux-device-driver

I have a FPGA(connected by PCI). This FPGA has 4 memories. I want to create:

- dev/memory1_FPGA
- dev/memory2_FPGA
- dev/memory3_FPGA
- dev/memory4_FPGA

With this, users programs can access to different memories. But when you create a module, you can only create a single dev/memoryFPGAx. Am I right?

Is it possible what I want to do? How can I do it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the linux kernel version you have ????

Comment: *"But when you create a module, you can only create a single dev/memoryFPGAx. Am I right?"* -- No, you're not right.  A properly written device driver should be serially re entrant, and be able to handle more than one instance of the device.  For example, look at an Ethernet MAC or serial port driver.  You'll find only one copy of the driver in the kernel, yet you can have multiple devices.

Comment: My kernel is 3.16. So, is it possible what I want?

Comment: Yes, it has always been possible, you have to check the minor in your open function.

Comment: Does anyone another specific answer? The steps that I follow are:

alloc_chrdev_region(&first,0, 4, "nameDevice"); //I want 4 devices
device_create(c2,NULL,first,NULL, "name");
cdev_init (&char_dev,&char_fops);

Any idea how to configure this?